# using returned json values in calls not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Trying to use the values I return from my php yet there are not working properly.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    $('#delete').on('click', function () {
        var $form = $(this).closest('form');
        $.ajax({
            type: $form.attr('method'),
            url: $form.attr('action'),
            data: $form.serialize(),
            dataType : 'json'
        }).done(function (response) {
            if (response.success == 'success') {

                // fade out the deleted comp
                $("#c"+response.computer_id+"").fadeOut("slow");

                // remove from the drop down
                $("#comp_selection option[value='#c"+response.computer_id+"']").remove();

            } else {
                alert('Some error occurred.');
            }
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

I am returning from the php file :

```
echo json_encode($ajax_result);
```

which is returning :

```
{"computer_id":1,"success":"success"}
```

EDIT:  I found a small error in code outside of this where I was returning a different value than expected.  All is well and the above was indeed correct to start with.

Comment: what is it supposed to return?

Comment: What does your console, in your developer tools, say? (F12 in IE, ctrl+shft+I in GC).

Comment: {"computer_id":1,"success":"success"} is what the console shows for response... the problem is accessing those variables in my response function.  Is "+something+" not the proper way?  For instance in the fadeout and remove calls I would want #c1 in this particular example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should debug using firebug or whatever developer tools you have in your browser - firebug in Firefox is very good for this as you can see the JSON data passed back from the AJAX call.

That said, your issue is that the data is probably under response.d - so look at response.d.success and response.d.computer_id

Comment: As I said earlier... I have used FF and it shows the correct json values being returned.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the content you are receiving from your PHP server is sent as simple text, and must be sent with the headers set for JSON content:

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to make a difference.  I know the if (response.success == 'success') { call works... it is the referencing of response.computer_id in the calls below it that doesn't seem to be.